# Service Account unable to access Google Drive despite having the right access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I'm facing this issue with the Google Drive File access using the Composer account .
The same composer is able to access the file in another environment(same GCP project) using Composer1 but the new environment with composer2 gives this error - Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.

I tried elevating permissions of the service account too but didn't help , as the account already had required permissions. Appreciate if someone can guide on how to troubleshoot or fix it. Thanks !

Update - Found the composer2 environment is missing below Google API scopes but unable to find out a way to add it in composer2.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

Comment: Are you trying to access to federated tables?

Comment: no, just trying to load a google sheet into Bigquery table.

Comment: yes but in an automated way, not with your user credential, correct?

Comment: yes both environments use the same service account, the only difference I could find in the composer environment which doesn't work is that it's missing API scopes . Tried but have been unable to add it so far .

Comment: Did you authorize the service account to access to the drive location?

Comment: yes, the same service account is able to access the same file in a different composer instance(composer1)

Comment: Did you read this section with composer 2? It runs on top of GKE (autopilot) and use the workload identity service to obtain credentials. You shouldn't use the right authentication method, and therefore not the correct service account, that's why you have a permission issue. See more here: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/access-control#composer-sa

Comment: yes I've granted service account this role and also tried making the service account Project Owner but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth scopes are not supported by `Composer2`  as it relies on GKE Autopilot.
In Composer 2 access in general should be managed via permissions assigned to the environment service account [link 1](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/access-scopes#console), [link 2](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/authentication#service_accounts).

However, in some cases when you need to specify an OAuth scope like with this Google Sheets connection, this is required to be done directly in the [method call](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/authentication#user_accounts). According to the  [Drive access documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#enable-google-drive) , you can set this with the Python API in the BigQuery client in the following way:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import google.auth

# Create credentials with Drive & BigQuery API scopes.
# Both APIs must be enabled for your project before running this code.

credentials, project = google.auth.default(

    scopes=[

        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",

        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",

    ]

)

# Construct a BigQuery client object.

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project)
```

An option you could also try would be to use the BigQuery API directly in your DAG instead of the Airflow operator and to enable drive authentication from the call.